# How to run genymotion over the http injector VPN

Tags: android, android-emulator, vpn, android-virtual-device, genymotion

In my computer, HTTP injector VPN software is always running. But genymotion android emulator is not working with the HTTP injector VPN. Android emulator is not starting when HTTP injector run. As the reason i found in internet, genymotion is use IP range to communicate with the android virtual device. But when the VPN is running, genymotion cant to communicate with the Android virtual device. How can I solve this issue? I wants to run HTTP injector and Genymotion emulator same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your VPN to ignore/exclude the host-only interface local IP. See https://support.genymotion.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002718258-Genymotion-Desktop-and-VPN

Comment: I try this reason is HTTP injector is not support to exclude IP addresses

Comment: Then, it cannot be used with Genymotion. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks you any idea about other software instead of HTTP injector